# Automatic vassal transfer

Tags: crusader-kings-2

When I give away a newly acquired county title, then give away the holding titles, the holding vassals are automatically transferred to the new count vassal. Is this intentional? If it is, then why do the holding vassals stay my direct vassal some of the time?

Comment: I've given away counties I hold every title in (most common after winning them in a holy war) without selecting 'also include lower titles', then created vassals for the lower holdings and had them remain my direct vassals. This is unbalanced if you can hold them long enough for the tax penalties wear off, because the count vassal has a high boost to opinion to offset the 'desires controls' maluses, and the lower vassals don't count for your limit. But I've never been able to keep lower vassals if they were created before giving away the county capital. Does that match what you've experienced?

Comment: @Dacio Hmm... it might work differently if you use the "Create New Vassal" button rather than give the baron level title to an existing character.

Comment: @Dacio Nope, both work the same way. I just acquired a county through a holy war, granted the county title to an unlanded relative, then created a new vassal for the city holding and granted the bishopric to another unlanded relative. Both the city and bishopric ended up automatically becoming vassals of the count.

Comment: It might affect it if the vassals are your dynasty. I will test.

Comment: @Dacio I meant that the counts ends up with the holding vassals in both situations.